# Trackpad and keyboard problems

Tags: mojave, mouse, trackpad

My keyboard is working oddly. The right side shift does not work, but the left side shift command button will. The trackpad will click, but it stopped working to move the cursor around.

The trackpad works perfectly if I start up computer using Command-D, so for the 2 minutes it takes for the diagnostic test to complete I can move the cursor using the track pad, so it is not the hardware. Today I did not have my mouse near my computer to be able to choose my user at startup so I just pressed the arrow key on the keyboard and it moved my cursor over to my user icon for me to sign in.

This shows me that something is telling my computer to listen to the keyboard and not the trackpad. It is not the setting in Accessibility that says ignore built in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present - that is unchecked. This is something going on with keyboard settings. Can I use terminal to set default settings?

MacBook Pro Retina 13 inch mid 2014 - Mojave

Comment: Are you able to use the mouse or keyboard properly when you boot up into safe mode (hold down shift)?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you may have the settings on for Mouse Buttons, which allow the arrow keys to navigate the mouse. I believe this is under Accessibility or maybe Keyboard or Mouse/Trackpad, depending on the MacOS version.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204434#mousekeys

Comment: What you are saying sounds like the settings I think are the problem also. I still have this problem and it has been a long time now. I no longer mess around in the Accessibility settings. I really got in there and was exploring it when this happened. Im used to how it is now. I still am very curious and would love to fix it. I just bring it up because its not a trackpad problem that needs to be replaced. If it was it would not work during the diagnostic 2min testing start up.  It works duding that time only. What ever type of start up that is it works.